# Machines.xcdatamodel Entities randomly deleted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

**Description**

Basically, i have around 6-7 entities in my data model and have corresponding NSManagedObject subclasses for them. All but two of them have mysteriously vanished for some unknown cause. At first, i thought it was simply a display bug, seeing as the subclass swift files were still their, and since it is a beta Xcode version. But, upon trying to save to one of these vanished entities, i get an error stating that the object doesn't exist. I would upload code snippets or pictures to illustrate the point, but it highly unnecessary, and my work wi-fi blocks almost every image hosting site. Just take my word for it. I have 7 subclasses, and only two entities in the data model. If anyone can help me figure out/prevent this problem from reoccurring, you would be a blessing. Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you generate them again?

Comment: As in, remake the data model entities? @Bek

Comment: As in, regenerate the model files from your .xcdatamodeld file.  Do you get an error, or do they regenerate fine?  Which ones are still there, the `+CoreDataProperties` files, or the ones with just the entity names?

Comment: So far, I haven't gotten any errors trying to regenerate the lost entities. All of the generated .swift files for the entities remained intact. Only the entities actually listed in .xdatamodel were completely removed. @Bek

Comment: There is nothing in Xcode that would be expected to cause this, ever. Does your version control software (e.g. git) show that the file has been changed?

Comment: Forgive me, for i am a massive noob in regard to xcode, but Blame is what i would use to check changes, correct? @TomHarrington. For in that case, it shows 'Cannot Blame directories' for the data model.

Comment: That's not an Xcode thing, it's git. The normal git command would be "git status" to see what files have changed, and "git diff" to see what those changes are. If you're not using the command line, there are many good apps that work with git (though Xcode's git integration is not the best).

Comment: Hmm, well i am not sure i know how to do that. I know that i never made changes to the file, if that helps. I am the only one working on the project.
@TomHarrington

Comment: You can examine the model file with any xml editor. There are known bugs even in the production version of xcode's core data editor. In the editor you can see if your entities are still there or not. If not, use a backup or recreated them. the diff will show you changes, too, even if you didn't make them.

Comment: Have you created or attempted to create a data model version? (This would create a versioned xcdatamodeld file within an xcdatamodel bundle.) if yes then add information about that to your question. If no then I'd recommend you rebuild you data model in another temporary Xcode project and replace your existing xcdatamodel file with the rebuilt model file.

Comment: I will try this when I get to work @andrewbuilder

Comment: I appreciate all of the responses from everyone!